# Jenkinsfile: master nightly build (only if changes)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile. Currently, it triggers only for pull requests and the master branch.

For the master branch, however, I do not want it to build every time it is merged into. Instead, I want it to build only at night, only if there were changes since the previous build, and to combine all those changes.

Is this possible?

Currently, the build triggers are set using the Jenkins configuration, not the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: You can turn off triggers for master and set up a periodic build for master only. When triggered, the build can determine if there were changes since the previous one, and exit if there haven't.

Comment: Can you describe how this is done?

Comment: To turn periodic build, you need `triggers { cron (env.BRANCH == "master" ? "H 2 * * *":"" ) }`. To run on non-master branches, `when { expression { env.BRANCH != "master "}}`. As of determining changes, I have no idea what a "change" means at your project. It may involve e.g. some digging into the output of `git log`.